# Ensuring A Variable is Initialized by Promises Before Executing Further Code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

```
function loadStrings(file){
    var strings = [];
    fetch(file).
        then(response => response.text()).
        then(data => strings = data.split("\n")).
        then(printStrings(strings));
}

function printStrings(strings){
    console.log(strings.length);
    for(string of strings){
        console.log(string);
    }
}
```

In this example, `console.log(strings.length)` prints zero. I thought attaching a `then()` after assigning to `strings` would ensure that `strings` was written to before I actually tried to print it out. How can I ensure that they're written to before I work with them?

Comment: `printStrings` is being invoked immediately and `.then` is recieving the _result_ of that as its callback. I think you may have meant to write it as either `then(printStrings)` or `then(() => printStrings(strings))`.

Comment: @CRice Thank you so much. This cleared up a misunderstanding on my end.